# how to see the writing of the text c # winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following code that should write letter by letter the string that I send but when it starts to write it really blocks the application and then shows me what it wrote that I can do

```
simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry("pruebva").Sleep(typingDelay);
```

the application crashes and then you see the text already written as I can see when each character is written

https://ourcodeworld.co/articulos/leer/520/simulando-eventos-keypress-de-la-manera-correcta-usando-inputsimulator-con-c-en-winforms

```
 private async void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            var simulator = new InputSimulator();
            int typingDelay = 100;


            Cursor.Position = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(171, 80));

            simulator.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry("id-cellphone");
            simulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

            //enviar
            Cursor.Position = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(585, 577));
            simulator.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();



            simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry("probe_text").Sleep(typingDelay);
            simulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);
            simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
            simulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);
            simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            simulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);

            simulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
```

thanks it worked

```
simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry("pruebva").Sleep(typingDelay);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            simulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
```

I can see when you write the text at last thank you very much

Comment: Replace `Thread.Sleep(5000);` with `await Task.Delay(5000)`, since you have made the handler `async` (don't you have a notification in VS that warns you about an `async` method that doesn't `await` anything?).

Comment: Would your life be simpler if you just used SendKeys with a large delay? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/how-to-simulate-events?view=netdesktop-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application does not crash. Windows will report that a program is not responding when it stop processing operating system messages for 5 seconds. And guess what happens when you do `Thread.Sleep(5000)`. Yep, five seconds of "do nothing" right there. It is preventing the UI thread to handle messages.

Please use [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) like this: `await Task.Delay(5000);`. And yes, event handlers can be async.

See also:

- [About Messages and Message Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues) to learn about operating system messages.
- [Preventing Hangs in Windows Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/preventing-hangs-in-windows-applications) for an explanation of how Windows decides an application is not responding.
- [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) and for guidelines using `async/await`.